# NSLog versus CCLog

Tags: iphone

What are the possible differences between the two? And which is better and in what respect? Are there situations where to use them?

Comment: An link-only answer below [offers this link](http://www.cocoacrumbs.com/blog/?p=69). It is liable to be deleted as an answer, so I am preserving it here.